# information from database not showing

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to get all the information from a table called 'agenda' to show on my webpage when it has been approved but im having trouble

```
  <?php
$agenda_id = $_GET['agenda_id'];
include 'library/connect.php';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE approval = 'approved' AND agenda_id = '$agenda_id'");

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Subject</th><th>Duration</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['subject']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['duration']. "</td>";



}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
include 'library/closedb.php';
?>
```

Comment: **Do not put user input into SQL queries.** How many times...

Answer (score 3):

`echo "</tr>";` goes inside your while loop.

Comment: still aint working the heading of the tables is showing on the webpage but the data from the database aint showing on the webpage its blanc